# How to make Kubernetes' RESTful api available from remote machines?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have set up a kubernetes cluster running on AWS. What I want to do now is to control the cluster from remote machines, for example, my macbook pro.

I've learned that Kubernetes has RESTful apis, and Kubectl can serve as a proxy.
By running :
`kubectl proxy --port=8001 &`
I can access the RESTful api with curl, for example:

```
curl http://localhost:8001/api
```

Then I found that I can only curl the localhost. If I curl from a remote machine with the following command:

```
curl http://dns-to-the-k8-machine:8080/api
```

I will get a "Connection refused." I wonder what is happening here? And is there a way to easily access the apis remotely?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you provisioned your cluster, the API server may be listening over a different port. Have a look at your `kubeconfig` file (`~/.kube/config`), in there should be a section which has the server you are connecting to.

Also, your cluster may be using certs or some other type of authentication which you'll need to pass as well. Those will be outlined in the same kubeconfig file.

When using `kubectl proxy`, kubectl is handling the pieces mentioned above automatically, and proxying back to your laptop over localhost.

Comment: Thank you Steve. The kubeconfig works perfectly. I can now access the cluster from remote machines. But there is a tiny problem. When using the kubeconfig as the authentication, I am only authorized to access the cluster by communicating with the kubernetes master node's 443 port via its private IP. This means I can only access the cluster from another aws instance but not my own laptop. I wonder is there a way to authorize me to access the cluster via master node's public IP?

Comment: How did you deploy the cluster? You'll need to give some sort of public facing IP or load balancer endpoint pointing to the private ip of the api server.